# Why do I have unexpected empty space between two <div>s placed in two separate line?

Tags: html, css, overflow

```css
.text-overflow{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.sub1{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(165, 90, 90, 0.4);
}
.sub2{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(91, 96, 163, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="text-overflow">
        <div class="sub1"></div>
        <div class="sub2">
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

you can see in the following, there is some white space that I don't know where they came from?!

[image]

Would anybody help me get rid of this issue?

Comment: A `<p>` has by default a `margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em` so even an empty `<p>` generates space... Change to `p { margin: 0; padding: 1em 0 }` and the space will disappear as padding collapses in an empty `<p>`.

Comment: BTW: [w3schools: HTML Element Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp) will show HTML elements default values at the bottom of their respective pages...

Comment: @RenevanderLende You made me get rid of this issue! Thanks a lot.

Comment: yw, here's a nice post on the use of `margin` I just now came accross: [The Rules of Margin Collapse](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/rules-of-margin-collapse/). But actually, I hardly ever use margins at all. I prefer the `* { box-sizing: border-box }` and set all default margins to 0 and use `padding` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
 * { 
         margin: 0px;
         padding: 0px;
         box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

This will work :)
but to be honest I m not sure why it happend in this case.

Comment: Oki, how @Rene van der Lende told in comments, its by default..

Comment: Yes, the problom was with the margin of <p> tag! I just added `margin:0;` to `.sib2 p` inside `style.css` and then everything became ok!